# Mapping to an JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I wanted to do a very basic mapping to JS Object from some array of integers;

```js
[1,2,3,4,5].map(val => {num: val})
           .forEach(result => console.log(result));
```

But as you can see it returns all undefined, is it due to the usage of curly brackets that is confused with lambda's body part? Using a boring syntax works though;

```js
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(val) {return {num: val}})
           .forEach(result => console.log(result));
```

Also this;

```js
[1,2,3,4,5].map(val => {return {num: val}})
           .forEach(result => console.log(result));
```

Is there no way to achieve what I am trying to do with lambda notation? Since the sleeker the better IMO

Comment: This is most certainly a duplicate, but the tl;dr version is - wrap your object literal in parenthesis `[1,2,3,4,5].map(val => ({num: val}))`

Comment: @Damon oh, I couldn't find the exact question, that is why wanted to ask, sorry~

Comment: no worries, wasn't reprimanding you or anything - the comment was more because I knew it would be closed as a duplicate but was too lazy to look for the "original" - it's a common problem :)

Comment: @Damon yeah I did search but couldn't find, btw however obsolete this comment is, I love the image in your profile, made me chuckle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(val => ({num: val}))
       .forEach(result => console.log(result));
```